# How can I check if it includes more than one things?

Tags: javascript, include

Is there way to check if something includes more than one thing?
My code didn't work when I did this:

`if(variable.includes("a" || "e")) {...}`

I thought it would work because of "`||`" but it only worked with "a", only checked if theres "a" and if there isn't stopped the code.

Sorry if any grammar mistakes or bad explanation.

Comment: It should be `if(variable.includes("a") || variable.includes("e")) `, you are checking for only truth value.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code:

```js
if (['a', 'e'].some(v => variable.includes(v))) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is most likley not a great solution but if your variable is an array (eg. `array = [a, h, a]`)

then you could try:

```
items=0;
numbers.forEach(function(){ //does a function for every item
items+=1; //will add one for every item
});
```

then do:

```
if (items>1) {
   //code that would run if there is more than one item
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an iteration and check with includes with the optional values.

```
variable.some(v => ["a", "e"].includes(v))
```